# Git repository - how to replay newer commits made to old repository, to modified repository after running git filter-branch

Tags: git

At the company I'm doing work for, we've recently migrated a Subversion repository to Git, but in the process, branch and merge points were lost, leaving us with a bunch of perfectly parallel unlinked branches. Because they have no branch points, git is unable to merge cleanly. We can't redo the migration because people have already been pushing additional commits to each of the different branches.

We decided we want to repair the git repository by extracting a list of branch and merge points from the subversion repository, matching them up to commit IDs in the git repository and then running `git filter-branch` to rewrite all of the parent references.

That part worked fine. I did some test merges between branches to confirm that the surgery worked correctly and so far, so good. The issue is that during this process, the team has continued to work, adding various commits onto their individual branches, and because filter-branch causes new commit IDs to be generated, I have the case where the team's new commits are parented onto the old commits and I need to somehow get those commits now applied to the new rewritten tree.

I know that git rebase is often used for this kind of thing, but rebase seems to only work with common branch points, which is no longer the case.

I also tried to use git cherry-pick, but I haven't been successful with that as I don't know how it's supposed to work, which means I don't know how to interpret the unexpected output it's giving me and what I have read about how to use it is not particularly clear, either in terms of what commands to use or what the expected output *should* be.

I've tried to illustrate the problem below:

[image: Git Tree Surgery]

- Note that we are on Windows - Linux commands are unavailable unless via Git Bash, which comes with msysgit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of branches that need these fixes, I'd be tempted to do something like the following for each branch:

```
git rebase --onto H' H J
```

This takes any commits between `H` and `J` and applies them on top of `H'` (where `H'` is the new ID of `H` in your middle diagram).

This would work for the cases where there's a linear topology, but you'd need an extra flag for the other cases:

```
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto I' I M
```

This should preserve your merge topology containing `K` and `L`.

I also find this sort of problems a lot easier to resolve with [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) at my side (making sure to `set commit-order = topo` for maximum usefulness).